# Android application event handling

Tags: java, android, events

Is there a standard set of Listener/Observer/Observable classes in Android for managing application events in Android?

I'm not talking about UI or other Android API events, but rather custom app events like `GameOverEvent`, `LevelClearedEvent`, etc.

Is there a preferred interface to implement/extend so that I can implement things like:

```
public void addGameOverListener(GameOverListener listener)
```

Comment: I used the built in [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) class to handle events. It processes requests asynchronously off the main UI thread, by way of intent requests. Each intent is added to the IntentService’s queue and handled sequentially. A decent getting started tutorial for IntentService [is available at mobiletuts](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/).

Answer (score 3):

It's easy,, you just need to create your own EventListener

```
public interface onGameFinishedListener {

    public void onGameFinished(GameView gameView);

}
```

and some class which has onGameFinished() method

```
public abstract class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    List<onGameFinishedListener> listeners;
    public GameThread gameThread;
    protected int width;
    protected int height;
    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        width = 320;
        height = 480;
        listeners = new ArrayList<onGameFinishedListener>();
    }

    public abstract void init();
    public void registerGameFinishedListener(onGameFinishedListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
    protected void GameFinished(GameView gameView) {
        for (onGameFinishedListener listener : listeners) {
            synchronized(gameThread.getSurfaceHolder()) {
                listener.onGameFinished(gameView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then you implement the onGameFinishedListener in your activity or view which you want to do operation when the game finish,

```
public class RocketActivity extends GameActivity implements onGameFinishedListener {

private final int MENU = 0;
private final int END = 1;
private final int CONFIRMATION = 2;
private RelativeLayout layout;
private RocketView rocketView;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    rocketView = new RocketView(this);

    rocketView.registerGameFinishedListener(this);
    rocketView.init();
    layout.addView(rocketView);
    setContentView(layout);
}

@Override
public void onGameFinished(GameView gameView) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            showDialog(END);
        }
    });
}
```

}

there. no need to rely on Android for EventListener. :)

Comment: some note : RocketView is a View that inherit GameView. so basically it's a GameView :)

Comment: Yeah, that's very similar to the code I have now. But I was wondering if there is a standard API for adding/removing listeners and firing events, rather than writing things manually (even though it's quite simple, as you demonstrated). For example, in GWT they provide an EventBus, and all (de)registration and even firing is all taken care of for you.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) by GreenRobot?

It is basically a pretty standard implementation of an eventBus for handling application wide events.
It provides inter-thread communication which is quite neat.

Pretty similar to what you get for [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html#events)